# MS Access VBA code to run specific queries based on Combobox selection on form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm currently trying to develop VBA code (case statement) that will run a specific query based on the name of the query that the user selects from a combobox on a form. Currently the query that is being run is not aligned with what the user selects from the combobox.

For example:

- when the user selects PlantNames (QryID 5) instead of running the qryPlantsLatin query (which is correct), it is running the qryNewPlants2 query (which is incorrect).
- when the user selects PlantInventory (QryID 3), instead of running the qryNewPlants2 query (which is correct), it is running the qryPlantsLatin query (which is incorrect).
- when the user selects PlantInventoryAvailable (QryID 4) instead of running the qryPlantInventoryTotal query (which is correct), it is running the qryPlantsLatin query (which is incorrect).

**CODE: VBA – Event Handler Used – After update**

```
Private Sub cboPlantQrys_AfterUpdate()
Select Case PlantQueries
Case Me.cboPlantQrys = "5"
     DoCmd.Close
     DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPlantsLatin" 
Case Me.cboPlantQrys = "3"   
     DoCmd.Close
     DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryNewPlants2"    
Case Me.cboPlantQrys = "4"
     DoCmd.Close
     DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPlantInventoryTotal"
Case Else
     MsgBox "Improper Selection"
End Select
End Sub
```

**ComboBox – cboPlantQrys – Row Source SQL**

```
SELECT tblQueries.QryID, tblQueries.QryData, tblQueries.QryName, tblQueries.QryGroup
FROM tblQueries
WHERE (((tblQueries.QryGroup)="Plants"));
```

Unfortunately I’m not quite sure how to fix this as the Row Source SQL and After Update Event VBA seem logical to me (but obviously I'm missing something).

Comment: Are these "action" queries (e.g. UPDATE or DELETE) queries you're executing or SELECT queries you're opening to view?

Comment: I think your `Case` syntax is wrong. Use `Select Case Me.cboPlantQrys` at the start of the block, then `Case "5"` for the first clause (and so on for all clauses). Presently I think your case sections are being interpreted as truthy or falsy and those items are compared to `PlantQueries`, which is not what you want. See [the syntax here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
Private Sub cboPlantQrys_AfterUpdate()

    Select Case Me.cboPlantQrys.Value
    Case "5"
         DoCmd.Close
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPlantsLatin" 
    Case "3"   
         DoCmd.Close
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryNewPlants2"    
    Case "4"
         DoCmd.Close
         DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryPlantInventoryTotal"
    Case Else
         MsgBox "Improper Selection"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, since the name of the query to be executed appears in your ComboBox RowSource, you could simplify your code quite a bit.

Here is your ComboBox RowSource as stated in your question:

```
SELECT tblQueries.QryID, tblQueries.QryData, tblQueries.QryName, tblQueries.QryGroup
FROM tblQueries
WHERE (((tblQueries.QryGroup)="Plants"));
```

That means that the ComboBox will have 4 columns in it at runtime.  When referencing ComboBox or ListBox columns in Access VBA code, the column numbering starts with 0 (zero).  So, the `QueryName` column would be column 2 (since it is the 3rd column in your RowSource).

Now, just check that a valid selection has been made (i.e. the ComboBox is not null or blank) and then execute the query, pulling the name dynamically from your ComboBox recordsource.

```
Private Sub cboPlantQrys_AfterUpdate()

'Easiest way to check for Null or Empty String is the following
'When you concatenate a possible Null with a zero length string
'the result is a string, therefore if the Length of this is greater
'then zero, we know the user chose an item in the ComboBox list.
If Len(Me.cboPlantQrys & "") > 0 Then
    DoCmd.Close
    Docmd.OpenQuery Me.cboPlantQrys.Column(2)
End If

End Sub
```

With this code, you no longer have to update the VBA code as you add or remove queries (records) in your `tblQueries` table.  This code will dynamically handle any number of rows in your table.

Comment: Thanks Jericho:) I will definitely keep this in mind moving forward as I can definitely see the value:)